# Why charges don't lose potential in a resistance free loop?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, electric-circuits, charge, potential-energy

If a battery to a current was like the gravity to a massive object, so the potential rise in the battery is like lifting the massive object above earth's surface, so when charges get closer to the negative terminal they should lose potential so much as the massive object loses it falling? However,because there is no resistance, by assumption, in this loop, we know that the potential will not drop, as charges loose potential not because they get closer to the negative terminal, as I believe they should if this analogy between gravity and electricity is true, of the battery but only when they encounter a resistance in the way. The massive object would lose potential even if it falls in a complete vacuum with no possible resistance, so why this is not the case in circuits?

Answer (score 0):

The analogy can be done for example thinking of a centrifugal pump, where the outlet is connected to a vertical pipe that goes up to a given height. There, a connection let the water returns to the inlet of the pump through another vertical pipe.

Bob is manually driving the pump, and his work is equivalent to the energy released inside the battery due to the chemical reaction. What limits the flow is the required power to lift the water, in a similar way that happens to move the charges in a battery in short circuit.

Answer (score 0):

> we know that the potential will not drop, as charges loose potential not because they get closer to the negative terminal, as I believe they should if this analogy between gravity and electricity is true, of the battery but only when they encounter a resistance in the way.

The charges do lose potential as they move through the electric field.

In a circuit that has reached steady state, charges inside the circuit rearrange so that the electric field is exactly proportional to the resistance.  *In the circuit*, the two are linked.

If you have a test charge moving through space (rather than charges confined to a conductor), this may no longer be true.  The test charge can lose potential as it moves through the field.  But without a resistance, it will gain KE.